# Windows does not know how to run node script (Angular CLI, General Windows issue)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, windows

This questions isn't necessarily specific to the Anuglar CLI, but that is where I am having problems.

My systems was working perfectly until some new installs and Windows updates occurred.

Now when I try to run the angular cli, it asks me what program to run the script with.

```
ng serve // Creates a popup and fails to run
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng //Fails in same way
```

If I manually run the binary with node it works fine

```
node C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng //Works great
```

In case it is relevant, here is some version info:

```
Node version: 
  v6.10.0
NG version: 
  @angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.2
  node: 6.10.0
  os: win32 x64
Windows Home 10
```

So, I think my PATH is setup correctly and that somehow Windows no longer knows how to correctly use node to run ng.

Any ideas on how to fix or workaround this?

I tried uninstalling/installing node, but that didn't fix anything.

For now I'll just create an alias and dream of the day I don't have to develop on Windows anymore. Thanks for the help.

Comment: what does the popup say?

Comment: It's just the standard windows popup asking me which program I want to run it with listing out a handful of my installed applications (notepad, etc.).